# Ethernet client over Wifi Raspberry

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian, raspberry-pi

Is there a possibility to create a "bridge" between the wireless adapter and the ethernet adapter in a Rapberry PI 3 whitout having routing involved?

The use case is as follows: I need to connect a PLC with ethernet to a wifi network. The PLC does only respond to incoming packets, otherwise it remains silent. I cannot use NAT, as the protocol has the PLC check the sender IPAddress as part of the validity of the packet and viceversa the receiver checks the PLC's address for validation. In principle the wifi part should expose the ethernet packets as they are and should accept packets for the PLC as if they were send simply over a cabled network.

I did some research but I only found examples where the wifi and ethernet adapters are in different networks and are routed.

Comment: This probably belongs in StackExchange's Rasberry Pi community, there is a duplicate question here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51057/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-wireless-bridge-to-ethernet

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a bridge with the **brctl** utility.

```
# brctl addbr br-lan
# brctl addif br-lan eth0
# brctl addif br-lan wlan0
```

Instead of configuring IP addresses on the individual interfaces, you have to do that to the bridge. That was it, the kernel takes care about all the low-level stuff automatically.

See [the linux documentation project](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/BRIDGE-STP-HOWTO/set-up-the-bridge.html) for more detailed advice.

Bridges may also be filtering packets. This can be controlled with the **ebtables** utility.

Comment: Just an FYI, this question and it's answers pretty much states it doesn't work on the Rasberry Pi3, and this is specific to it (not a general Linux limitation). https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51057/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-wireless-bridge-to-ethernet

Comment: Ah, bummer. Had upvoted Dmitry's answer right on the spot.

Comment: It's not a Linux limitation? Does it depend on the kernel in use?

Comment: It's a hardware/firmware limitation, so some USB Wifi adapter with Atheros chipset may help. You may also want to use a dedicated router board and OpenWrt/LEDE Linux instead. See http://openwrt.org